# Pass PDF blob via Flow HTTP Post Callout in Salesforce

Tags: post, request, salesforce

I have an AWS lambda function, which helps me parse a PDF document to extract relevant data and fill a Salesforce object with this data afterwards in a Salesforce flow. I have a running setup, performing a HTTP POST callout using a pure (manually created / coded) apex class and I would like to switch to the new [Flow HTTP Callout](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_http_callout.htm&type=5) element.

---

### TL;DR

How can I pass a ContentVersion.VersionData base64 encoded blob of a pdf file to a Flow HTTP POST callout?

---

### Apex approach

Using a **ContentDocumentLink** object (describing a PDF file / attachment linked to another object (e.g. a Case)) with a *ContentDocumentId* variable I retrieved a **ContentVersion** object by matching the *ContentDocumentId* on this object.

I pass this *ContentVersionId* of the **ContentVersion** object to an apex class, which retrieves the base64 encoded Blob of the PDF object like so

```
public static Blob get_content_version_blob_data(String ContentVersionId ) {    
  Blob pdfblob = [SELECT VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :ContentVersionId].VersionData;    
  return pdfblob;    
}
```

I then create the **HttpRequest**, performing the callout and get the response.

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint(<my_endpoint_url>);
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'pdf');
request.setHeader('Accept-Charset', 'UTF-8');
request.setBodyAsBlob(pdfblob);

Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
Map<String, Object> d_response = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
```

This approach is working perfectly fine, but with manual apex coding.
Hence I tried to transfer it to the new [Flow HTTP Callout](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_http_callout.htm&type=5) method.

---

### Flow HTTP Callout approach

I created a simple flow with the following steps

**1. Get ContentVersion**

- Retrieves the **ContentVersion** object, based on a match of the *ContentDocumentId*
- The output is stored in a **ContentVersion** object named *CurrentContentVersion*, storing the variables *ID* (ContentVersionId) and *VersionData* assumed to hold the blob data, as seen in the apex code)

**2. Set callout body variable**

- The *callout_body.body* variable is assigned as the *CurrentContentVersion.VersionData*

**3. Execute the HTTP Callout**

- As described in salesforce help [Configure an HTTP Callout Action](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_http_callout_configure.htm&type=5) I created a new variable *callout_body*, using the Apex-Defined data type and referencing the automatically created apex class *ExternalService__MyService_CalloutMyService_IN_body* for my callout input body.
- Note that in the JSON schema the request body of my **ExternalService** is defined as string
  Assign the response to my local variables

*JSON schema for request body in ExternalService*

```
[...],    
"requestBody": {    
  "content": {    
    "application/json": {    
      "schema": {    
        "type": "object",    
        "properties": {    
          "body": {    
            "type": "string"    
          }    
        }    
      }    
    }    
  },    
  "required": true    
},    
[...]
```

Here are some screenshots of my flow
[image: Salesforce flow preview]

This approach already fails at step 2, assigning the *callout_body.body* variable with error message

```
Error Occurred: Value of class core.filemanager.FileBlobValue is not a ValueType: STRING
```

I can relate to this error message, since my JSON schema describes the body as type *string*. Hence I tried to change the JSON schema to type *object* for the body like

```
[...]    
"body": {    
  "type": "object"    
}    
[...]
```

But doing this, I cannot select the apex class *ExternalService__MyService_CalloutMyService_IN_body* any more for my *callout_body* input variable (see step 3), only the **_OUT_2XX* and **_OUT_2XX_data* options are available.

Same behaviour / issue when trying a *binary* input format for the body

```
[...]    
"body": {    
  "type": "string",    
  "format": "binary"    
}    
[...]
```

---

### Final question

Has anyone managed to define a blob style base64 encoded object type for the input body of a Flow HTTP POST callout to pass the blob to the external service?

Any help is very appreciated, thanks!

---

*This [question](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V000076BflZSAS) has also been asked on Salesforce Trailhead.*

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Any pointers?

Comment: Not with the standard Flow HTTP Callout functionality of Salesforce. But you can try an unofficial SF solution No Code Web Callouts (https://unofficialsf.com/no-code-web-callouts/) where a request body can be send as blob. I am still using the Apex solution.